# Movie or series involving a woman living with other people, who is attacked, and then defends herself and those people with machine/robot-like powers

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I can remember in bits of a trailer. There was a woman shown as living with people. Then when they are attacked, she seems to possess powers like she is a machine (robot), and defends her people.

I saw this trailer in mid-2021. I think the language was English. The woman's hair was short and I'd guess she was in or around her thirties.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you see this trailer, and in which country and/or language did you see it? Also, can you describe the appearance of the woman, i.e. her hair length/colour, approximate age, ethnicity, etc?

Comment: In mid 2021. I think the language was English. Her hair was short i think age around 30s i guess.

Comment: And it was not planet Earth. Its in a different planet

Comment: How can you tell that it was a different planet?

Comment: Live-action or animated?

Comment: Ok i found it. Thanks for your insights. I have seen the trailer this year only. It was a series. "Raised by wolves"

Comment: On SE sites it's perfectly acceptable to write an answer to a question that you pose (self-answering we call it).

Answer (score 4):

As can be seen in the comment above, the original poster identified this as the 2020 HBO series "Raised by Wolves".

Per the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_by_Wolves_(American_TV_series)) summary of the premise:

> [T]wo androids—Father and Mother—tasked with raising human children on
> Kepler-22b after the Earth was destroyed by a great war. As the
> burgeoning colony of humans threatens to be torn apart by religious
> differences, the androids learn that controlling the beliefs of humans
> is a treacherous and difficult task.